# javascript $(window).width() property not working in in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer

I've following Div with absolute position:

```
<div id="target" style="height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 275px;"></div>
```

What I am doing is calculating the screen **horizontal resolution** using javascript and then using that obtained width, I am calculating the width and the left position of my **"target"**  div as follows:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var targetWidth = windowWidth * 0.7;
var targetLeftPos = windowWidth * (15 / 100);
$('#target').css({ 'width': targetWidth });
$('#target').css({ 'left': targetLeftPos });
```

This code working perfectly in all the browsers but in **IE this code is not working** at all causing the target div **not having width and left position style**, causing all my designing to be just destructed.

Is there any way to detect the clients browser and then do the alternate code if the detected browser is IE.

Please tell me how should I detect clients browser and what alternate code should I execute for IE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out the problem... the external jquery plugin **stickyscroll.js** was causing the problem. It is stopping the execution of all js on the page (happening only in IE). When I removed it, the above code working all the way accurate for IE also....

Answer (score 3):

instead of `$(window).width`, use

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
```

Comment: `${window}.width` should be `$(window).width();`. I have changed it

Comment: var windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth; I've tried this one too, but its also not working for IE.

Comment: can you try with document.documentElement.clientWidth

Comment: when in IE i goes to developer tool and goes to script tab and starts debugging, and then refresh the page the js works accurately.. and now the div is re positioned accurately as i wanted. But this is not the solution to my problem as this is manual method. The problem that think is that the IE not executing the js automatically